# MySQL Workbench connect to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, mysql-workbench

I have a .mdb file on my computer that I would like to convert into a MySQL Schema and I have found that there is a migration tool within Workbench. However it doesn't seem to allow you to connect to a .mdb instead it looks for a server. How should I either link to my file or host my file easily as I have not done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://mysql.com/products/workbench) doesn't currently support migrations from MS Access. But you can still use the old [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-migration-toolkit) which does support MS Access migrations.